# Print HTML "p" Nodes Only

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to use HTMLParser to print anything enclosed in "p" tags of an HTML document **only**, and not anything else in other types of tags.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if "p" in tag:
            print "Data in <p>:\n"
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print data

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><h1>The Lorem Ipsum</h1></head>'
            '<body><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p><b>'
            '<h2>Click Next for the next part.</h2><h3>'
            'Coming Soon!</h3><p>Thanks.</p></body></html>')
```

Using this shows the headings as well, which I don't want.

However, when I try to change some things so it should only display the "p" for the "data" part as well, nothing enclosed in the "p" tags show up.

```
    def handle_data(self, tag, data):
        if "p" in tag:
            print data
```

I'm also confused how I'm correctly supposed to form my code for this to work.

Comment: Have you looked at BeautifulSoup? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4

Comment: what do you want to print for `<p><em>what about me!</em></p>`?

Comment: One of the reasons why beautifulsoup may be a better option is that it is more forgiving of messy html. For instance, an html document may forget to close a `<p>` tag which can be confusing for a state machine dependent on the end tag to stop printing data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of when you are in `<p>` tag:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    __in_p = None

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'p':
            self.__in_p = True
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'p':
            self.__in_p = False
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.__in_p:
            print("Encountered   some data:", data)
```

This code won't work if the tag may be nested in itself (`<p>` can't, `<div>` can). You could use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (`pip install beautifulsoup4`), [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) (`lxml`), to parse html.

Answer (score 0):

Since `HTMLParser` presents data in a separate event, you need to keep track of state so you know what to print. Also, `'p' in tag` will catch any tag with a 'p' in it but not a capitalized P.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.last_tag = ''
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.last_tag = tag
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.last_tag in ('p', 'P'):
            print data

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><h1>The Lorem Ipsum</h1></head>'
            '<body><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p><b>'
            '<h2>Click Next for the next part.</h2><h3>'
            'Coming Soon!</h3><p>Thanks.</p></body></html>')
```

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yeah, I was just looking at your solution. I wasn't sure from the question how to handle sub elements. Maybe it should be a count to deal with p's in p. BTW, check for 'P' as well as 'p' and I think I like your solution better.

Comment: I've asked OP about nested elements. My answer handles both `<p>` and `<P>` as is.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I see `if tag == 'p':`. Does HTMLParser lower case tags?

Comment: html tag names are not case-sensitive

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - correct, that's why I checked for both. Turns out that HTMLParser does lower case the tag.

Comment: it is pointless to check both `'p'` and `'P'` here. As I said the answer works as is.